Ros2 Iron, Tutorial Webots, Setting up a robot simulation (Basic) Connection Issue
Following the basic tutorial with the goal to use webots with ros2, I've run into the following problem:
[INFO] [webots-1]: process started with pid [20800]
[INFO] [webots_controller_my_robot-2]: process started with pid [20802]
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 50 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 45 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 40 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 35 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 30 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 25 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 20 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 15 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 10 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 5 seconds...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Giving up...
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
[ERROR] [webots_controller_my_robot-2]: process has died [pid 20802, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/share/webots_ros2_driver/scripts/webots-controller --robot-name=my_robot --protocol=ipc --port=1234 ros2 --ros-args -p robot_description:=/ros2_ws/install/my_package/share/my_package/resource/my_robot.urdf'].

I followed the simple instructions and copy/pasted (ctrl+C/V) all code. I couldn't find anything online and don't know where to start debugging this error myself.
Has someone had a similar problem, knows how to fix this or can help me understand what's wrong?
